# Reading uploaded text file contents in variable

Tags: javascript, html, file, input

I want to read string from text file and save it in variable . What  I did:
HTML:

```
<div>
        Select a text file: 
        <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    </div>
    <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');
    var newString;
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;
        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
            }
            newString=reader.result;  //SAVE RESULT 
            alert(newString);
            reader.readAsText(file);    
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
        }
    });
```

}

I want to save text from file and alert it. But it doesnt work.

I did it:

```
var tfile;
        var reader = new FileReader();

        function rdfile(files)
        {
            tfile = files[0];
           reader.readAsText(tfile, 'CP1251');

            reader.onload = function(e)
            {
                str = e.target.result;
                alert(str);
            };
        }
```

But it doesnt work too. I alert many different symbols but not my text.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your code from your first attempt:

```
newString=reader.result;  //SAVE RESULT 
alert(newString);
reader.readAsText(file);
```

1. Get the result
2. Alert it
3. Do the thing that generates the result

You have to read the file before you can look at the text you get from reading it!

Move steps 1 and 2 in to the `onload` event handler you already have.

---

Now look at your second attempt. You never call `rdfile` and you never call `readAsText`.